# Named HandlerInterceptor for Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, jax-rs

Is there a way to create a named HandlerInterceptor for Springboot. I'd like to create an annotation such as:

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsAuthenticated {
}
```

So only those requests that have this annotation would use the annotated HandlerInterceptor. I have already done this with a JAX RS ContainerRequestFilter but, now I want to do the same for Spring.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to put some authorization logic inside that? If yes, you are trying to reinvent the wheel called Spring Security. But in fact, handler interceptor does not know nothing about the controller, so what do you want to mark this annotation?

Comment: I want this annotation in order to validate some params that may require a bunch of requests (but not all of them, that's why I'd love to use an annotation). On the other hand, I've read about Spring Security and authentication manager, but I don't like filtering the authenticated requests by URL, I'd rather filter the requests by an annotation instead, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you have `@PreAuthorize` annotation, you can mark your methods you  want to secure. And it can evalute `SpEL` expressions like `#service.method(paramerets)`. [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) for it. There is a bunch of default methods or you can create your own.

Comment: I didn't know about @PreAuthorize annotation, I'll take a look thanks! As you can see I am a beginner in Spring. Is there a way to use annotations for other filters, in order to validate some params in a bunch of requests?

Comment: It depends on your business logic. As for me, If I need to validate security things or infrastructure things, I prefer to use Filters. If I need to validate business entities, I will use simple validations in controller (`@Validated` or simply `@Valid` marked objects). Also you can use interceptors (`HandlerInterceptor`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll take a look to @Valid, do you know whether I can use this annotation for query params and path params as well as for body objects? Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164532/discussion-between-bogdan-oros-and-fvod).